# How do I take the specific value of a JSON formatted string?

Tags: python, json

Write a function named "get" that takes a JSON formatted string as a parameter in the format "{"attack": float, "decay": float, "sustain": float, "release": float}" and returns the value at the key "attack".

```
import json
def get(JSON):
    load = json.loads(JSON)
    dictionary = {}
    attack = [f[0] for f in load]
    attack1 = dictionary.update(attack)
    for key, value in attack1.items():
        if key == 'attack':
            return value
```

My question is how do I take the specific value ('attack') in a JSON formatted string?

Comment: Try using  `return attack1['attack']`. No need to use `for` loop and `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've loaded it using json.loads(), you've converted it from a string to a dictionary. That means that the load variable you assign in load = json.loads(JSON) is already a dictionary, and you can access it using normal python dictionary syntax from there:

```
import json
def get(JSON):
    load = json.loads(JSON)
    return load["attack"]
```

Answer (score 0):

So if your question is how to obtain the value of attack from JSON then do this:

```
load = json.loads(JSON)
load["attack"]
```

json.loads() makes the json into a python dictionary.